# Should I write question when I know answer?

Tags: discussion

I had a problem for which I couldn't find solution on the Internet. I found a solution and I think that the solution for the problem is useful and somebody could have the same problem. Is it OK to write my problem with my solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is explicitly allowed per the https://superuser.com/faq

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.