# Official stance on asking questions (that you answer) that might apply to several people

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I write question when I know answer?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2163/should-i-write-question-when-i-know-answer)

Scenario:

- You've struggled with a problem/issue for a while and didn't post it on Super User because you wanted to figure it out yourself.
- You decide others might benefit from knowing what you figured out
- You post a question: "How do you [blah]"
- Answer your own question with a very detailed post and accept.

Is this proper for Super User? I mean, we are a website that strives to amass lots of useful information to be accessible to everyone (plus we're very well indexed in Google). Does this conform to the rules?

Also, what constitutes something that's interesting enough for everyone else to know how to do. Is "How to edit my Arch distribution to make it smaller" just as valid as "Unlock the system user account in Windows XP"?

Comment: The other post does not address the issue of more obscure questions. How is it seen if I post every challenge I come across and answer it?

Comment: It does, but if you make a habit of it, people won't view it kindly